# Let $Y_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i(X_i+1)}{n}$ . Find a number $c$ such that $Y_n \to c$

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables, each
having a $Uniform[0, 0.5]$ distribution. Let $Y_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i(X_i+1)}{n}$
. Find a number $c$ such that
$Y_n \to c$ ($p$ above the arrow)

Attempt:

$Y_n = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i(X_i+1)}{n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2}{n} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}{n}$

Not sure how to go about this. I believe I need to find their expectation but not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density is $2$ on $(0,0.5)$ and $0$ elsewhere. $EX_1=2 \int _0^ {1/2} x \, dx =\frac 1 4$ and $EX_1^{2}=2\int _0^ {1/2} x ^{2}\, dx =\frac 1 {12}$ so $c=\frac 1 4+\frac 1 {12}= \frac 1 3$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Law of Large Numbers $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n X_i}{n} \rightarrow  \mu$$
where $$\mu = E(X) = \frac{1}{2}(0 + 0.5) = \frac{1}{4}$$
Also 
$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2}{n} \rightarrow  \mu^2 + Var(X)$$
where $$Var(X) = \frac{1}{12}(0.5)^2 = \frac{1}{48} $$
So 
$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2}{n} \rightarrow  \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{48}$$
Therefore
$$c = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{48} = \frac{1}{3}$$